# How to EXPORT_SYMBOL uniquely with the function's arguments?

Tags: c, linux, gcc, linux-kernel, kernel-module

As we all know when using `EXPORT_SYMBOL("function name")` we get into the symbol list in System.map the function name as symbol.

```
c041bc90 b packet_sklist
c041bc94 b packet_sklist_lock
c041bc94 b packet_socks_nr
c041bc98 A __bss_stop
c041bc98 A _end
c041c000 A pg0
ffffe400 A __kernel_vsyscall
```

My question is: is there any compile option, hacking, macro or anything in the world enables you to include also the arguments of the function ?

i.e

```
c041bc90 b packet_sklist (list of arguments...)
```

two reasons for these:

1. you can export `do_something(int a)`  and export `do_something(int a,int b)` .
2. you won't have bugs when using extern functions in kernel modules
   which have mismatch in the arguments.

Comment: this is something like operator overloading and that is not supported in pure c.

Answer (score 0):

The no 1 reason you've shown, even if EXPORT_SYMBOL supports argument, it won't support variable argument, cause Linux uses C.